# What is indicated by a well pump temporarily recovering when shutting off the power for several hours?

Tags: plumbing, well-pump

We have a water pressure issue in all fixtures of the house. We first replaced the whole-house water filter which helped right away, but the next morning there was almost no water (10 psi instead of the usual 30-35 psi). After making a few calls to local specialists, we tried one suggestion that seemed to help: turn off the well pump power for a few hours (more than 20 minutes seems to be required, but the shortest we've tried is 2 hours of leaving off the power). This gets us water pressure back to about 30 psi after about half an hour, but soon after it quickly drops again.

Any suggestions on what to do in this situation, or what might be happening, would be appreciated.

**Other information**

- We are the only house on the well, in the finger-lakes region of New York State. No new houses immediately near us.
- After turning the pump back on, the pressure will go up to 40-45 PSI in less than 5 minutes, and then start to drop (usually 30 PSI after half an hour or so) and down to 8 PSI overnight. However, it certainly drops faster with use. The main issue seems to be that it never seems to go back up, unless we turn off the power for a couple of hours and then back on.
- House was built in 1983 or 1984, we purchased 5 years ago.
- We have a submersible pump  (at least I'm pretty sure). I've attached photos below of the system, as well as the well head, though I didn't open it up yet, so I'm guessing that photo is not very informative. And it has a snake on it for a bonus!
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]

I'm not really sure what the box/unit in the lower left corner of the first two images is, though probably not relevant.

**Other information 2**

- This is a new problem, though this is the first time we've had 4 people at home all the time, and during a drought.

Comment: well going dry?

Comment: Yes, are there any nighttime uses of water? Sprinklers, water softener etc.?

Comment: No night-time uses that I know of, but this is happening in the day as well. We have had a drought, but our grass is still green (we live at the bottom of a hill which tends to stay wet and green even during droughts). Turning off the pump for a while always seems to fix the issue, but from what I read, it does sound like the well could be dry. However, I'm very inexperienced in these matters.

Comment: I would suspect a leak.  One way to check for a leak if you are the only house on the well is be sure everything is turned off and then turn off the pump. If the pressure is dropping you have a leak.   Wells have very different characteristics when it comes to production and recovery. Another way to check for a leak is to put a pressure gauge somewhere on the house (a hose bib is a great location). Take a reading then turn off the valve at the well/pressure tank/pump house or whatever is the main cutoff at your well system.  If the pressure drops without usage, you have a leak.

Comment: ...ran out of space for a comment. We can better help you if you can describe your water system.   Do you have an electrical  pump cutout for "sucking air" or electrode system in the well casing to shut off the pump in case of low water level in the well?  There are ways of dealing with a low producing well but they tend to be quite a bit more complex than just a submersible pump, controls and pressure tank.

Comment: What sort of pump do you have? In well submersible, exterior to well two pipe (jet pump) or exterior to well one pipe (shallow well suction pump)? Your basic options are that the pump is having an issue (such as overheating) or your well is having an issue (such as low production, OR you have a leak that's using up your production until you shut the pump off.) **It takes 30 minutes after you switch the pump on after it's been off for 2 hours to build to 30 PSI?**

Comment: What area are you in ? My area it is extremely rare to have a dry well , it can depend on the area and the depth of your well , have there been new houses built close to your location this can lower the water table to below your wells depth. More info could provide a better answer than a comment.

Comment: Are you new to this house or have you occupied it for years? Is this a new problem or has it been a problem for some time. As others have said, more information is needed. Your best bet may be to call in a well driller for advice. Being at the top or bottom of a hill usually has little to do with well capacity. The well's capacity is determined by the water table you are taking water from. But please, more information is needed.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback - I've added an "other information" section. I'll add more as well if required; we're still collecting data.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson from your description it sounds like this is a leak - would this be between the well and the pressure tank?

Comment: Wow. I've not seen a pump like that before so I dk what it is. Do you have any history of the well? Any drilling logs?  Usually the State or County keeps those records. How far down is that, what looks like a pump head?  How big is the casing? That almost looks like a "surface well" that collects water from a high water table near ground level, sometimes called a cistern. Sorry, but you are going to have to do some more research on what type of well you have. From what you posted, the pump does not look like a typical submersible pump.

Comment: oops. meant to also talk about the potential leak.  Can you hear the pump when it runs? Does it run when no one is using water? If so, to identify the leak, you should (if possible) turn the valve off on the right side that leads to the house and see if that makes a difference.   Do you have a crawl space, have you checked the plumbing there for leaks? It's unlikely but possible.   Most likely place for a leak would be between the pump and pressure tank.   Put an ear to it when you are having issues and tell us what you hear.

Comment: dang, one more thing:  I think the blue box in the lower left of your 2 first pictures is a condensate pump that pumps out condensation from an A/C unit (furnace/air handler).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I added an answer, credit to the well drillers.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, when the well drillers came over, they agreed with many of the comments: it was either a bad pump, or a leak. They ruled out the leak after testing the water pressure directly at the well head. The submersible pump was over 275 feet down (at the very bottom of the well). The pump was determined to be as old as the house: 36 years old, and only 0.5 horsepower.